# Jquery - Remove last append item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not familiar with Jquery in the slightest admittedly although it is in the task of things I need to learn. I currently have a project I am working on which requires an add / remove function similar to what is on an invoice.

I would like to be able to add a "Remove" function to the last item appended incase mistakes get made etc

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentItem = 1;
  $('#addnew').click(function(){
   currentItem++;
   $('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<br>Product: <select class="form" name="Product'+currentItem+'" id="product'+currentItem+'" ><option value="Aramax Classic Tobacco">Aramax Classic Tobacco</option><option value="Aramax Energy Drink">Aramax Energy Drink</option></select>    Nicotine: <select class="form" name="nicotine'+currentItem+'" id="nicotine'+currentItem+'"> <option value="N/A">n/a</option><option value="3mg">3mg</option><option value="6mg">6mg</option><option value="12mg">12mg</option></select>    Quantity:<input class="form3" name="qty'+currentItem+'" id="qty'+currentItem+'" type="number" /><br>';
   $('#data').append(strToAdd);

  });

 });
$('#delete').on('click', function() {
$('#items').parents("br").remove();

});

//]]>
</script><div class="form2">
 <form method="POST" action="invoicereg.php" id="data" name="sub">
    Product:
    <select class="form" name="product1" id="product1">
         <option value="Aramax Classic Tobacco">Aramax Classic Tobacco</option>
         <option value="Aramax Energy Drink">Aramax Energy Drink</option>
     </select>
    Nicotine:
    <select class="form" name="nicotine1" id="nicotine1">
      <option value="N/A">n/a</option>
      <option value="3mg">3mg</option>
      <option value="6mg">6mg</option>
      <option value="12mg">12mg</option>
    </select>
      Quantity:<input class="form3" type="number" id="qty1" name="qty1"></input><br>

    </form>
   <br>
    <input class="button" type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" /> 
    <input type="hidden" form="data" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
     <input class="button" type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="Remove" /> 
    <input class="button" type="submit" form="data" value="SUBMIT">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can show and / or explain to me how this is done it would be greatly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Will it be okay to add a delete option to each new row added or you want just the last one to have the delete option...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rapped the content of your form and the content you add with a `<div>`.

Then you can do `$('#data > div').last().remove();`

`#data` is the id of your form.

`#data > div` will select all the `<div>` that is a first child of your `form`.

`.last()` selects the last element.

**Note** if your would like to keep atleast 1 element in your form you can do this:

```
if ($('#data > div').length > 1) {
   $('#data > div').last().remove();
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentItem = 1;
  $('#addnew').click(function(){
   currentItem++;
   $('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<div><br>Product: <select class="form" name="Product'+currentItem+'" id="product'+currentItem+'" ><option value="Aramax Classic Tobacco">Aramax Classic Tobacco</option><option value="Aramax Energy Drink">Aramax Energy Drink</option></select>    Nicotine: <select class="form" name="nicotine'+currentItem+'" id="nicotine'+currentItem+'"> <option value="N/A">n/a</option><option value="3mg">3mg</option><option value="6mg">6mg</option><option value="12mg">12mg</option></select>    Quantity:<input class="form3" name="qty'+currentItem+'" id="qty'+currentItem+'" type="number" /><br></div>';
   $('#data').append(strToAdd);

  });

 });
$('#delete').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#data > div').length > 1) {
    $('#data > div').last().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</script><div class="form2">
 <form method="POST" action="invoicereg.php" id="data" name="sub">
   <div> 
   Product:
    <select class="form" name="product1" id="product1">
         <option value="Aramax Classic Tobacco">Aramax Classic Tobacco</option>
         <option value="Aramax Energy Drink">Aramax Energy Drink</option>
     </select>
    Nicotine:
    <select class="form" name="nicotine1" id="nicotine1">
      <option value="N/A">n/a</option>
      <option value="3mg">3mg</option>
      <option value="6mg">6mg</option>
      <option value="12mg">12mg</option>
    </select>
      Quantity:<input class="form3" type="number" id="qty1" name="qty1"></input><br>
</div>
    </form>
   <br>
    <input class="button" type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" /> 
    <input type="hidden" form="data" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
     <input class="button" type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="Remove" /> 
    <input class="button" type="submit" form="data" value="SUBMIT">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

use some over all div like `<div class="items">yourcode</div>` .Then apply with `$('.items').`[**`last()`**](https://api.jquery.com/last/)`.remove()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentItem = 1;
  $('#addnew').click(function() {
    currentItem++;
    $('#items').val(currentItem);
    var strToAdd = '<br><div class="items">Product: <select class="form" name="Product' + currentItem + '" id="product' + currentItem + '" ><option value="Aramax Classic Tobacco">Aramax Classic Tobacco</option><option value="Aramax Energy Drink">Aramax Energy Drink</option></select>    Nicotine: <select class="form" name="nicotine' + currentItem + '" id="nicotine' + currentItem + '"> <option value="N/A">n/a</option><option value="3mg">3mg</option><option value="6mg">6mg</option><option value="12mg">12mg</option></select>    Quantity:<input class="form3" name="qty' + currentItem + '" id="qty' + currentItem + '" type="number" /><br></div>';
    $('#data').append(strToAdd);

  });

});
$('#delete').on('click', function() {
  $('.items').last().remove()

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form2">
  <form method="POST" action="invoicereg.php" id="data" name="sub">
    <div class="items">
    Product:
    <select class="form" name="product1" id="product1">
      <option value="Aramax Classic Tobacco">Aramax Classic Tobacco</option>
      <option value="Aramax Energy Drink">Aramax Energy Drink</option>
    </select>
    Nicotine:
    <select class="form" name="nicotine1" id="nicotine1">
      <option value="N/A">n/a</option>
      <option value="3mg">3mg</option>
      <option value="6mg">6mg</option>
      <option value="12mg">12mg</option>
    </select>
    Quantity:
    <input class="form3" type="number" id="qty1" name="qty1"></input>
    <br>
</div>
  </form>
  <br>
  <input class="button" type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add new item" />
  <input type="hidden" form="data" id="items" name="items" value="1" />
  <input class="button" type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="Remove" />
  <input class="button" type="submit" form="data" value="SUBMIT">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to wrap the added items in a div, say something like:
`<div class="added-item"></div>`
then when you click the remove button you will have to find all these added items
`var added_items = $('.added-item');`
and then remove the last element
`added_items.last().remove();`